# How to display multiple nodes of a content type on a page displaying a parent node?

Tags: nodes, theming

I have a content type called **PRODUCT**.  Each of these product's has an entity relationship to one or more other **PRODUCT** items that are similar.  When a user views a **PRODUCT**, using the themed output for that **PRODUCT**, I would like to display the other similar **PRODUCT**'s below it.

Initially I used the entity full item display option in the content output and that worked fine, but I really need each node in a  tag of its own and not have the one product group the related product items under it in the output which is what the entity display filter does.

Entity Display Output....

```
<div class="main-node">
  ...
  <div class="entity-node1">
     ...
  </div>
  <div class="entity-node2">
     ...
  </div>
</div>
```

But what I would like is the following.

```
<div class="main-node">
  ...
</div>
<div class="entity-node1">
  ...
</div>
<div class="entity-node2">
  ...
</div>
```

Where is the best option to create this type of output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a `Views Attachment` to attach another view `After` your first view.

Another similar option is the [Entity Views Attachment module](https://www.drupal.org/project/eva):

> "Eva" is short for "Entity Views Attachment;" it provides a Views display plugin that allows the output of a View to be attached to the content of any Drupal entity. The body of a node or comment, the profile of a user account, or the listing page for a Taxonomy term are all examples of entity content.
>
> The placement of the view in the entity's content can be reordered on the "Field Display" administration page for that entity, like other fields added using the Field UI module.

So the nice thing about the EVA module is that it allows you to easily place and manage the View from the Field UI of your content type. Thus, making the administration of this *tacked on view* a little bit easier for site administrators.